# Many to many relationship with core data: how to populate intersection data?

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many

I have no idea how to implement the following using Core Data.

> employee <<-->> company

This means that an employee can work in different companies, and one company can obviously have many employees.

But in my core data, I want to store additional information, like "employee id" or "level of seniority". These data are linked to the relationship between the entities.
Normally these data are stored in intersection tables, but what with core data?

Thanks in advance, yassa

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without seeing more of your model, but would it make sense to have entities for `Person`, `Employee` and `Company`?

A `Person` could have a to-many relationship with `Employee` while an `Employee` has a to-one relationship with `Person`.

> Person <---->> Employee

Then an `Employee` could have a to-one relationship with a `Company`, and a `Company` can have a to-many relationship with `Employee`.

> Employee <<----> Company

Now you can store the personal details that aren't related to employment to any specific company in `Person`, keep the employee details such as "ID" or "seniority" in the `Employee` entity and all the company related information in `Company`.

Comment: So you're saying me to implement a data model with an intersection table:
`Person <-->>Employee<<-->Company`.
Is this the only available solution? Any other ideas? I was hoping that Core data was automatically able to manage this :(

Comment: Core Data is awesome, but it's not a wizard. You still need to define your graph. This isn't complicated stuff, this is standard database normalization...

Comment: And do you know how this can be represented on the iPhone user interface?
I mean: I insert a new company, then I want to associate a person and also record data about the employee...

Comment: This site is related to programming questions. Your UI is up to you.

Comment: I'm not fully convinced about this! :)
However I was only asking for hints on how this specific 1:intersection_table:1 relationship can be represented on a usable UI...